# How can I assure that newly created prod azure resources are locked by policy?

Tags: azure, automation, resources, locking

I'm an Azure administrator.  I want to assure that new resources created in production are automatically locked when they're created.  Is there a way to set that policy?  I know I can create locks with the CLI/GUI.  I need to do it automatically without scripting az commands.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.stefanroth.net/2020/02/03/azure-policy-audit-and-deploy-cannotdelete-lock-on-resource-group-based-on-tags/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Blueprints to do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/tutorials/protect-new-resources

or you can do it by scheduling a Runbook in an automation account. I have built a script for this that locks the Resource Groups that i have scheduled every night. Locking can have a negative impact on functionallity and sometimes its enoying if your resources gets locked to early.

In my code below i have excluded AzureBackup_RG_ since it breaks the functionallity of deleting snapshots which causes the backup to fail after a while.

```
<###########################################################################################################
#
# LckResourceGroup
#
# This script is intended to run daily to lock all resource groups to prevent accidential deletion
# of resources.
#
# Written by Daniel Björk - 2018-02-27
# Designed for Accigo AB 
#
#
# Ver 1.0 Date 2018-02-27
# First Version
#

Instructions
    1. Import Az.Accounts to the Automation Account
    2. Import Az.Resources to the Automation Account
    3. Create Runbook (Copy Powershell)
    4. Schedule runbook

#
###########################################################################################################>

# INFORMATION: Change Subscription name to enable on other subscriptions
$SubScriptionName = "SubscriptionName"
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

Add-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null

Write-Output "Select Subscription"

Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubScriptionName

$resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup | where {!$_.ResourceGroupName.StartsWith("AzureBackup")}

foreach ($resourceGroup in $resourceGroups) {
    Write-Output $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
    $lockId = (Get-AzResourceLock -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName).LockId

    #Remove-AzureRmResourceLock -LockId $lockId
    if (!$lockId -and !$resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName.StartsWith("AzureBackupRG_")){
        Write-Output "Locking Resource Group"
        New-AzResourceLock `
            -LockName ResourceGroupLock `
            -LockLevel CanNotDelete `
            -LockNotes 'Locks all resources in the resource group' `
            -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName `
            -Force
    }
}
```